# How to get returned json data after jquery post?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I'm trying to get returned data by json after jquery.post but...

```
    <script>
        function sendToJsonTitleConverter() {
            $.post("/engine/title-converter", {
                NewTitle: $("#NewTitle").val()
            });
        }
    </script>
```

MVC:

```
    public ActionResult JsonTitleConverter()
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Request.Form["NewTitle"]))
        {
            string title = myFunction.ClearTitle(Request.Form["NewTitle"]);
            var result = new LinkedList<object>();
            result.AddLast(new
            {
                Title = title
            });
            return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

**Returned Json:**

[{"Title":"test 21312 asdasd asas"}]

How can I get Title in javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a "callback", which are functions that are set to execute when an async operation is done. Sort of a "to-do", since you can't do sequential code for a non-sequential operation.

In this example, I prefer using the deferred style of adding a callback, so that the name of the function (in this case, `done`) is readable. You can additionally put `fail` and `complete` without being confused.

Additionally, you need to state that you are getting JSON data. jQuery sometimes fails in getting the type right, especially on their shorthand functions.

```
$.post("/engine/title-converter", {
    NewTitle: $("#NewTitle").val()
  },'json')
  .done(function(data){
    var title = data[0].Title
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
function sendToJsonTitleConverter() {
    $.post("/engine/title-converter", {NewTitle: $("#NewTitle").val()}, function(data){
         var title = data[0].Title;
         alert(title);
    }, 'json');
}
```

Cheers